# What is the significance of the Korean voting stamp?

Tags: history-of-korean

When voting at an election, Koreans mark their ballots with a specially shaped stamp. Does this stamp have any significance related to the Korean language?

The stamp is shaped like a "peace" symbol missing the left branch (a circle with some lines in it):

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 卜 (복)

...is the Hanja for 'fortune telling' or 'divination'.

From https://kuiwon.wordpress.com/2016/04/12/why-do-voting-stamps-in-korean-polling-booths-use-the-character-%E5%8D%9C/:

> The first elections in South Korea were held in 1948 under the
>   auspices of the US Army Military Government.  Voters at polling booths
>   used a circular stamp or sign (“○”) with no circumscribed shaped
>   inside to mark down their candidates of choice. Resources were so
>   inadequate that people resorted to using the round edges of pen caps
>   to indicate their votes. The Korean War from 1950 to 1953 devastated
>   the country even further. In the elections immediately after war,
>   voters used bamboo branches and even bullet casings to mark their
>   votes. While Korea’s economy vastly improved in the following decades,
>   the plain circular mark continued to be used.
>
> The plain circular mark, however, had a few practical problems. When
>   they are cast, the ballots on which the mark is recorded are folded.
>   In many instances, this caused in the dye being transposed onto the
>   contacting side, thereby resulting in invalid votes. In 1992, the
>   Chinese character 人(인) for “person” was added and circumscribed into
>   the circular voting stamp to remedy this problem. The addition of this
>   character shape, however, did not completely resolve the issue with
>   invalid votes, since the character 人 is somewhat symmetric. The dye
>   transposed onto the folded side of the ballot was still
>   indistinguishable from from the side where the mark was originally
>   stamp.
>
> During the presidential elections of 1994, another issue arose. The
>   character 人 was seen as too similar to the si-ot ㅅ in candidate Kim
>   Young-sam’s (金泳三, 김영삼, 1927-2015) name and ultimately viewed as
>   favoring him. (Kim Young-sam would indeed later go onto win the
>   presidential election, becoming the first civilian to hold the Korean
>   presidential office in three decades.) To address this problem, the
>   character 人  was changed to 卜(복). This alteration also finally
>   resolved the issue of invalid votes resulting from the dye being
>   transposed onto the other side of the ballot. Since the character 卜 is
>   asymmetric, election talliers would be able to distinguish the
>   transposed mark from the original mark.
>
> The character 卜 also carries multiple meanings, highly pertinent to
>   the rite of voting. It can mean “to foretell” (점치다), “to consider in
>   detail” (상고하다), or “to count” (헤아리다). And this is why the voting
>   stamps in Korean elections have the character 卜.

Answer (score 0):

In the international Semaphore Flag System, the symbol coincides with the following Latin alphabets and their potential interpretations:

D + V = Democratic Vote

D + G = Democratic Government/Governance

Comment: do you have any reference for this to prove this is what it stands for?